# Qt Creator debugging CDB variable value not accessible

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, windbg

Qt 5.12.2 for msvc2017, Qt Creator 9.0.1, Visual Studio 2019 installed.

during debugging I cannot see value of local variables of Qt types such as
`QDateTime`, I see `<not accessible>`.

How to fix that?

Comment: "How to fix that?" - one obvious option is to build a debug version of Qt yourself (from source) - then you can have unoptimized code and debug symbols. Which makes debugging a hell of a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio, you should follow the instructions on [Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/IDE_Debug_Helpers) to have the natvis file deployed.

The easiest solution is to install the VS add-in (linked provided on the page).
You can also simply download the natvis file and save it as instructed to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio <version>\Visualizers\qt5.natvis`, remove all occurrences of `'##NAMESPACE##::'` and you're done. (again, instructions are on the page).

You may need to restart Visual studio after installation.